# Maximum recursion depth exceeded error when passing a list to an __init__() method

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, properties

I am trying to create a basic mathematical programming environment, something like sage, but very basic. I have defined the class `functionClass`, and a subclass `poly` that inherits the attribute `functionClass.x` from its base class.

The base class `poly`'s `__init__()` method takes in a list (corresponding to the coefficients of a polynomial) named `coeffs` apart from using `functionClass`'s `x`.

For some odd reason I am getting a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` message at the objects first instantiation. I am a bit perplexed because it's all happened in `poly`'s `__init__()` method.... a quick pointer would be very helpful!

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import math
import operator

class functionClass:

    functions = {0: math.sin, 1: math.cos, 2: math.tan, 3: math.exp, 4: 'identity'}


    def __init__(self,option_code=0,x=0):
        self._option_code = option_code
        self._x = x
    @property
    def code(self):
        return self._option_code
    @code.setter
    def code(self,new_code):
        self._option_code = new_code

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self,new_x):
        self._x = new_x

    def f_x(self):
        if self.code in self.functions:
            return self.functions[self.code](self.x)

    def __add__(self,other):
        sum = self.f_x() + other.f_x()
        return sum

    def __sub__(self,other):
        difference = self.f_x() - other.f_x()
        return difference

    def __mul__(self,other): 
        product = self.f_x() * other.f_x()
        return product

    def __truediv__(self,other):
        quotient = self.f_x() / other.f_x()
        return quotient


#class poly(functionClass)-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class poly(functionClass):
    def __init__(self,coeffs,x):
        self.coeffs = coeffs
        print(self.coeffs)
        self.degree = len(coeffs)
        functionClass.x = x


    @property
    def coeffs(self):
        return self.coeffs

    @coeffs.setter
    def coeffs(self,new_coeffs):#TAKES IN A LIST
        self.coeffs= new_coeffs


    #test this
    def p_x(self):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(self.degree):
            sum = sum + (self.coeffs[i] * math.pow(x,i))
        return sum

    def __add__(self,other):
        pass

    def __sub__(self,other):
        pass

    def __mul__(self,other):
        pass
```

When I run `i=poly([1,1,1],1)`, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    i = poly([1,1,1],1)
  File "C:\Python\numInt.py", line 76, in __init__
    self.coeffs = coeffs
  File "C:\Python\numInt.py", line 88, in coeffs
    self.coeffs= new_coeffs
  File "C:\Python\numInt.py", line 88, in coeffs
    self.coeffs= new_coeffs
  File "C:\Python\numInt.py", line 88, in coeffs
    self.coeffs= new_coeffs
  [Previous line repeated 989 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

This isn't part of any homework or something like that, I'm just working on improving my python skills.

Comment: Where is your example of using this that is causing the problem?

Comment: What is the traceback? Also, I don't see how the docstring is relevant, I'm tempted to edit it all out. Is there anything in there we should actually be aware of that's relevant to the issue?

Comment: AH, I will edit it out in a few!

Comment: I already cut it out

Comment: let me edit the question and put in an example of the use that's causing the error...

Comment: Your `ceoffs` setter override is calling itself.

Comment: @ScottHunter how so?

Comment: Maybe my understanding of the ```@property``` decorator is a bit off...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the setter of `coeffs` interacting with the line `self.coeffs = coeffs` in `__init__`

```
    @coeffs.setter
    def coeffs(self,new_coeffs):#TAKES IN A LIST
        self.coeffs= new_coeffs
```

Setting `coeffs` calls the setter, but the setter sets it again internally, causing an infinite loop. The usual (but not universal) convention is to append '_' to the name of the backing variable. So make your setter:

```
    @coeffs.setter
    def coeffs(self,new_coeffs):#TAKES IN A LIST
        self.coeffs_ = new_coeffs # Notice the _
```

and your getter

```
    @property
    def coeffs(self):
        return self.coeffs_
```

Comment: I just put the underscore in the front instead of the back...and it worked! There was a comment saying that the setter is calling itself, so i played around until i added the underscore

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved! I don't know why, but all I did was change `self.coeffs` to `self._coeffs` in `poly`'s `__init__()` method.